# Proving a theorem of logic

Tags: logic, philosophy, foundations

At the moment I'm going through a book which treats logic in a very rigorous axiomatic way. But I just got stuck in this theorem that I can't seem to be able to solve (I'm still trying hard). The thing is, that I already went through all the theorems before, and all the theorems after this particular theorem, but I still can't solve it.

This is the theorem I have to prove:

[image: Theorem]

The symbol 'y' is equal to 'and', because the book is in Spanish. At the moment, I'm going this way, and I think I'm 'very near' to prove it.

I start by the **axiom 2**, which it is the material conditional:

$
(R\implies S) \iff (\lnot R \lor S)
$ (1)

And also using the axiom but backwards:

$
(S\implies R) \iff (\lnot S \lor R)
$ (2)

I think the key is in two theorems I already proved.

**First theorem:**

If $A \implies B$ and $ C \implies D $ are both true, then $ (A \land C) \implies (B \land D) $ is also true

**Similarly, second theorem:**

If $A \implies B$ and $ C \implies D $ are both true, then $ (A \lor C) \implies (B \lor D) $ is also true

So by using this, I go this way. By using (1) and (2) and **theorem 1** I get:

$
(S \implies R) \land (R \implies S) \iff [(\lnot R \lor S) \land (\lnot S \lor R)]
$ is true

This is equivalent to

$
(R \iff S) \iff [(\lnot R \lor S) \land (\lnot S \lor R)]
$

But I haven't been able to match the other side through already proved theorems or axioms. Some help will be greatly appreciated.

---

**I'm editing to add the theorems of distribution:**

Let A, B and C be statements. Then:

$ (A \lor B) \land C \implies [ (A \land C) \lor (B \land C)] $ is true

$ (A \land B) \lor C \iff [ (A \lor C) \land (B \lor C)] $ is true

Comment: Do you know the way distribution works over logical OR and logical AND? This is one way to handle it:
$$(\neg R\vee S)\wedge(\neg S\vee R)=((\neg R\vee S)\wedge\neg S)\vee((\neg R\vee S)\wedge R)$$
And then repeat. It leaves you with something irritating, but that can be removed freely when the time comes as it has no impact on the value of the statement, a fact which may not be immediately obvious.

Comment: I forgot about it, thanks for the clue. I'll add the theorems regarding distribution to the post, I already proved those. I would say they are the the same you used, only that they are stated in a different way. I get near to the final of the proof, but not totally.
$$ [(\lnot R \land \lnot S) \lor (\lnot R \land R)] \lor [(S \land \lnot S) \lor (S \land R)] $$ 
I know by theorem that $(R \land \lnot R)$ and similarly $(S \land \lnot S)$ are false, but that's all. I think we are already there, I just have to find a way to get rid of those two things which are  unnecessary.

Comment: The $\vee$ operator is true if either one of its arguments is true. If one of them is always false, you can remove the $\vee$ and the false argument, leaving only the one that is potentially true. Check a truth table for the idea:
$$\begin{array}{ccc}p&q&p\vee q\\T&F&T\\F&F&F\end{array}$$

Comment: Thanks! When I took logic in my first courses, we used that syllogism; but at the moment I'm taking a course in Foundations of Mathematics, and the more important element seems to be rigour. I know that argument is true, and I have been thinking in it for the past two hours, but I don't know if I can use it, because it doesn't seem 'rigorous enough'.
I'm still having a trouble understanding what is 'rigorous enough', and what is not. Some theorems that I proved, seemed obvious and were difficult to prove; other seemed complex, and need some basic reasoning.

Comment: Well, after all I finished doing it this way. Only that I stated the argument you said as a theorem, then I went to proved it rigorously, and then I used it in this theorem. Thanks to everyone.

Comment: For future reference, "rigorous enough" depends on two main things: how well the subject is understood in general AND who is the intended audience for your proof.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [natural deduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_deduction):

**Theorem:** $(R\leftrightarrow S) \leftrightarrow (R\land S)\lor(\neg R \land \neg S)$

> **Proof ($\Rightarrow$)**:
>
> > 1) $(R\leftrightarrow S)$, assumption
> >
> > 2) $(R\rightarrow S)$, 1, $\leftrightarrow$-elim
> >
> > > 3) $\neg ((R\land S)\lor(\neg R \land \neg S))$, assumption
> > >
> > > > 4) $R\land S$ , assumption
> > > >
> > > > 5) $(R\land S)\lor(\neg R \land \neg S)$, 4, $\lor$-intro
> > > >
> > > > 6) $\bot$, 3,5, $\land$-intro
> > >
> > > 7) $\neg (R\land S)$, 4-6, $\neg$-intro
> > >
> > > > 8) $\neg R \land \neg S$, assumption
> > > >
> > > > 9) $(R\land S)\lor(\neg R \land \neg S)$, 8, $\lor$-intro
> > > >
> > > > 10) $\bot$, 3,9, $\land$-intro
> > >
> > > 11) $\neg (\neg R \land \neg S)$, 8-10, $\neg$-intro
> > >
> > > 12) $(\neg (R\land S)) \land (\neg (\neg R \land \neg S))$, 7, 11, $\land$-intro
> > >
> > > 13) $(R\land S) \lor (\neg R \land \neg S)$, 12, De Morgan's Law
> > >
> > > 14) $\bot$, 3, 13, $\land$-intro
> >
> > 15) $\neg (\neg ((R\land S)\lor(\neg R \land \neg S)))$, 3-14, $\neg$-intro
> >
> > 16) $(R\land S) \lor (\neg R \land \neg S)$, 15, $\neg \neg$-elim
>
> 17) $(R\leftrightarrow S) \rightarrow ((R\land S) \lor (\neg R \land \neg S))$, 1-16, $\rightarrow $-intro

Can you continue from here?

Comment: The course I'm taking at the moment is axiomatic, so natural deduction is out of the tools. But I already proved the theorem. I had to state a theorem, prove it and then use it to prove this one. But I appreciate your help.